# x-webkit-speech: onwebkitspeechchange is not reseting the value

Tags: javascript, html, input, webkit

I'm trying to reset my input value with onwebkitspeechchange event so that only speech text remains in value.

`onclick` on little mic removed the text

after click dialog pop up and value reset to initial text

Code:

```
<input name="s" type="text" x-webkit-speech="" id="s" value="What are you looking for?" onfocus="if (this.value == 'What are you looking for?') {this.value = '';}" onwebkitspeechchange="if (this.value == 'What are you looking for?') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'What are you looking for?';}">
```

I know that onblur event is doing this but how can I make an exception for onwebkitspeechchange so only speech reamain?

can't use placeholder attribute (doesn't work in ie 9)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and got it working with a simple JS function. Here's my solution:

```
<input x-webkit-speech="x-webkit-speech" onwebkitspeechchange="webkitSpeechChange(this);" name="myinput" value="<?php echo $this->__('Search entire store here...') ?>" class="search-query" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    function webkitSpeechChange(input) {
        input.value = input.value.replace('<?php echo $this->__('Search entire store here...') ?>', '');
    }
    //]]>
</script>
```

where `<?php echo $this->__('Search entire store here...') ?>` should be your default value.

Hope this helps :)