# Google voice search on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, speech-recognition

First off I am trying to create a temporary solution that I don't expect to work forever. Just an experiment if you will!

I have the following running!
What I am trying to do is initiate the voice search on page load.
Any ideas for a way to get this working!
Note: You will need chrome browser to see the mic input.

http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/99amf/

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

#mike {
font-size: 25px;
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
cursor:pointer;
border: none;
position: absolute;
margin-left: 5px;
outline: none;
background: transparent;
}
#txt {
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
}
</style>

<script>
var mike = document.getElementById('mike');
mike.onfocus = mike.blur;
mike.onwebkitspeechchange = function(e) {
console.log(e); // SpeechInputEvent
document.getElementById('txt').value = mike.value;  
};
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use webkitSpeechRecognition which doesn't require a button click to activate. Then just direct whatever text you capture into the input.

webkitSpeechRecognition will prompt the user to authorize the site to use the mic, but as long as that permission exists, it can start listening for user input as soon as the page loads. Make sure your site uses HTTPS so that the browser only asks the user for the permission once, and remembers it.

You might also want to check out [annyang](https://www.talater.com/annyang/), which is a JavaScript library that makes dealing with speech recognition super-easy.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the HTTPS comment? Or maybe a link with more info on that point. Thanks.

Comment: When you first activate webkitSpeechRecognition on a page, the browser will ask you to grant permission to this site to use your mic. Pages hosted on HTTPS do not need to ask repeatedly for permission, whereas HTTP hosted pages do.
You can see the difference by comparing http://www.talater.com/annyang/ and https://www.talater.com/annyang/

Comment: Thanks this is a very useful piece of non obvious info. And nice work on annyang, liked the simple facebook.js implementation.

Comment: Thanks. I'll be glad to see whatever you work on when it's ready.
And if you end up using annyang, let me know how it works out for you, and if there are any features which you think should be added/changed.

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. The most important reason being that it would be an [**invasion of privacy/security hazard**](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-xg-htmlspeech/2011Feb/att-0020/api-draft.html#security).  A user must ***willingly*** choose to be recorded (in this case, by mouseclick).  If the event can be emulated and the user is unaware that they are being recorded, there could be serious legal repercussions. Hope this helps!

---

***UPDATE:***

This is from a [document](http://www.w3.org/2005/Incubator/htmlspeech/2010/10/google-api-draft.html#security) about `Speech Input`:

> To minimize the chance of users unwittingly let web pages record speech without their knowledge, implementations must abort an active speech input session if the web page lost input focus to another window or to another tab within the same user agent.

Here are concerns from that same [document](http://www.w3.org/2005/Incubator/htmlspeech/2010/10/google-api-draft.html#security) :

> 1) Spoken password inputs can be problematic from a security perspective, but it is up to the user to decide if they want to speak their password.
>
> 2) Speech input could potentially be used to eavesdrop on users. Malicious webpages could use tricks such as hiding the input element or otherwise making the user believe that it has stopped recording speech while continuing to do so. They could also potentially style the input element to appear as something else and trick the user into clicking them. An example of styling the file input element can be seen at http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html. The above recommendations are intended to reduce this risk of such attacks.

Also, according to [this article from html5rocks.com](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API):

> the first time speech recognition is used, Chrome needs to ask the user for permission to use the microphone, in which case onstart only fires when and if the user allows permission.

With this in mind, it would be ***very difficult***, if not nearly impossible, to implement `onload` events without the user's consent, since Google has taken measures to protect against `malicious webpages`. Google has also prevented users from [simulating click events](https://code.google.com/p/html5rocks/issues/detail?id=594).

Comment: Its not possible or legality problem? This is for my sole use anyways so i am not worried about legal repercussion for I Am aware :). Thanks for the info though.

Comment: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-xg-htmlspeech/2011Feb/att-0020/api-draft.html#security states that User agents must only start speech input sessions with explicit, informed user consent. User consent can include, for example:Consent previously granted to always allow speech input for this web page.

Comment: @tman I will add more info to my original post, but I will answer that :)

Comment: So given that I do plan on using this for personal use do you think its worth looking for a work around or am i going against something that is prob to difficult to do.

Comment: @tman Well it depends... what exactly is your goal? Do you need speech recognition on a web browser?

Comment: Yes, In short! I need to be able to start the voice recognition using voice. I can open a web page with voice and it was at this point i was coming here to make the page listen on load!

Comment: @tman how are you opening web pages? Can you provide any code?

Answer (score 4):

After trying a bunch of stuff and researching, I found that:

> You cannot programmatically activate the speech input. This is to prevent abuse.
>   https://code.google.com/p/html5rocks/issues/detail?id=594

That's from google.

Tried like hell to make the jFiddle work. Used a bunch of jquery functions, tried target to simulate a click, a few third party stuff -- looks they've got it pretty well secured.

Comment: This page says"Consent previously granted to always allow speech input for this web page." If this where the case then wheres the issue?

Comment: I think I posted the wrong link at first. Posted the link on the google forums instead of the actual link to the google forms. All fixed now. Tried to crack this for ya but no go. At first I thought it was jFiddle giving me problems, then when I couldn't fix it I found that google developers were blocking this in the chrome code.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this approach:

[x-webkit-speech: onwebkitspeechchange not resting the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602736/x-webkit-speech-onwebkitspeechchange-not-resting-the-value)

If you look at the example they're doing something else entirely via

```
onwebkitspeechchange="webkitSpeechChange(this);"
```

I'd imagine you need to add that to your code.

Comment: the problem is simulating the mouse click on the mic button! Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Maybe, i'm missing something here, but in your fiddle you're calling a function you've never declared?

Answer (score -2):

The first thing that comes to mind is to use jQuery. Here is a little of how to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  startMikeInput();
}
```

This will initiate your mic input when the page is done loading. You will also need to reference the jQuery in your script tag. It might be helpful too to use an external js file.

Comment: If you are running it locally you will need to download jQuery and reference it correctly. I've run into problems with that before.

Comment: the startmikeInput(); is the problem this does nothing.